# Add list of dicts with same keys and values of type int

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, addition

In Python 3.5, if I have two dictionaries that have the same keys and integer values I can add them like this:

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
z = {**x, **y}
```

But what if I have a very long list of dictionaries that share the format of `x` and `y`? What's the syntax for `z` in this case?

Comment: If you don't need to update the dictionary, you could use a `ChainMap`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

Comment: `dict(ChainMap(*[x,y]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for an arbitrary number of dicts in a list, just use a loop, that is the idiomatic way:

```
z = {}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    z.update(d)
```

Comment: Turns out I formulated my question wrong, but you did answer what I asked so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {1:11}
>>> b = {2:22}
>>> c = {3:33}
>>> list_abc = [a,b,c]
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> dict(ChainMap(*list_abc))
{1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
z = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}

result = x.copy()

for d in (y,z):
    result.update(d)
```